# How does ngRepeat optimize the compile function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

via odetocode:

> [**The idea behind the compilation step is to allow for one time DOM
>   manipulation before the cloning – a performance optimization.**](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/28/compile-pre-and-post-linking-in-angularjs.aspx?utm_source=ng-newsletter&utm_campaign=8b09d965e0-AngularJS_Newsletter_6_3_146_2_2014&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_fa61364f13-8b09d965e0-96549981) [[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCFzn8fR5ohgTwp2YWhv?p=preview)]

#### So... when a directive is placed inside of an `ng-repeat` block, it is being instantiated multiple times, but the *compile* function only executes one times. *How does ngRepeat implement this optimization?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) docs have a neat example of what you ask:

```
Hello {{user}}, you have these actions:
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="action in user.actions">
        {{action.description}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

The documentation says:

> ...the template `<li>` element needs to be cloned and inserted into ul. But cloning the `<li>` element is not enough. It also needs to compile the `<li>` so that its directives, like `{{action.description}}`, evaluate against the right scope.

So this is how `ngRepeat` does it:

> `ngRepeat` works by preventing the compilation process from descending into the `<li>` element so it can make a clone of the original and handle inserting and removing DOM nodes itself.
>
> Instead the `ngRepeat` directive compiles `<li>` separately. The result of the `<li>` element compilation is a linking function which contains all of the directives contained in the `<li>` element, ready to be attached to a specific clone of the `<li>` element.
>
> At runtime the `ngRepeat` watches the expression and as items are added to the array it clones the `<li>` element, creates a new scope for the cloned `<li>` element and calls the link function on the cloned `<li>`.

So, to summarize:

- The element with `ngRepeat` gets compiled by `ngRepeat` itself, resulting in a linking functions that contains all other directives on the element (in this case, the interpolation directive for `action.description`)
- When items are added to `user.actions`, the element is cloned and gets a new scope, and the linking function is called on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that ngRepeat prevents the compilation process from descending into the <li> element via the combination of `priority:1000`, and `terminal:true`

Comment: Nice you found out! I was just looking at [the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js), but I missed `terminal`. Interesting to see how the `link` function works anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an optimization of `ngRepeat` - it is the same for every Angular directive (both built-in and custom).
The template is compiled once **for every instance** of your directive in your HTML template (but may be cloned or linked multiple times).

E.g. in

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="action in user.actions">...</li>
</ul>
```

`ngRepeat` will compile `<li ng-repeat="action in user.actions">...</li>` once and then clone and link it multiple times (one for every `action` that is found in `user.actions`).

Comment: What do you mean each template is compiled once? If you duplicate the markup including the `ng-repeat` and everything inside of it in the linked plunk, in the console you will see that the compile function executes twice. see [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NVCym3jSb4eMGVlLE2wF?p=preview)

Comment: The compile function is executed once **for every instance of your directive in your original template**. Angular-UI has a nice explanation of this: [Injecting, compiling and linking functions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#injecting-compiling-and-linking-functions)

Comment: @GilBirman: I updated the answer to clarify a bit. link's answer explains it in much more detail anyway (I probably wouldn't have posted mine if link's was there at the time :)).

Comment: Thx @link for the heads-up and useful link.